# Thunderpush : how can we add ssl support

Tags: ssl, websocket

How  to add secured ssl support in the thunderpush websocket server, i was looking in there doc but did not find any answers how to add the certificate file to the server.

not sure how we can achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Never tried it, but I guess you can use a haproxy with ssl terminate setup. Haproxy will accept ssl traffic and forward it to non ssl thunderpush backend.

Regards,
Vangelis